# How to auto-save to MongoDB with Mongoose without lag or freezing?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing a text editing app with Node.js & express and want to achieve Google Docs-esque auto-saving whenever the user edits their text.

Currently I'm doing this by saving to the database with AJAX whenever the user presses a key within the textarea. As soon as I start typing at any decent speed the saving process freezes up and doesn't save most of the content.
This however works perfectly when typing slowly.
I'm currently using mLab, MongoDB hosting, could this be the problem?

In fact, what is the best way to handle this task?

edit.ejs (front-end js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#board-lyrics').keyup(updateLyrics);
   $('#board-title').keyup(updateLyrics);

   function updateLyrics() {
     let boardData = {
        title: $('#board-title').val(),
        content: $('#board-lyrics').val()
     }
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: `./<%= id %>`,
         data: boardData,
         success: function(data) {

         },
         error: function() {
            console.log('error');
         }
      });
   }

});
```

app.js

```
app.post('/edit/:id', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => {
   let user = req.user;
   let boardId = req.params.id;
   let query = {"_id": req.user.id};
   let update = {"$set": {}};
   let index;

   for (let i = 0; i < user.boards.length; i++) {
    if (user.boards[i]._id == boardId) {
         index = i;
    }
   }

   update.$set[`boards.${index}.title`] = req.body.title;
   update.$set[`boards.${index}.content`] = req.body.content;

   let options = { new: true };
   User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(err, doc){
      console.log(query);
      console.log(update);
      console.log(doc);
   });
});
```

Comment: you should not update your db too frequently instead i would suggest is to store chunk of 50 characters and then save those chunks.

Comment: Alright thank you. I could also then make it save if the chunk character limit doesn't get reached within ~4 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, two things here.
firstly, it isn't a good idea to update your DB on every keystroke. Think about it. You are making a post request to your server more than once in a second with a payload and touching DB. Not ideal. So either you keep this data cached and save it once it crosses a threshold (say after one paragraph or X number of characters) or,

secondly, you can do some tweaks at the front-end side also here. Make sure you catch only valid or wanted keystrokes. Use reactive programming. Check for Rxjs and filter out invalid characters or catch only at a certain interval. Hope this will help.